# Discrepancy between EMF measures

Tags: measurement

Why, using a EMF tester on a smartphone in airplane mode, do I get a very low measure (\$< 1 mG\$), whereas using some applications which exploit the phone magnetometer, I get a very high value, something as \$35 \mu T\$? I get also a significant difference when I switch airplane mode off.

Comment: I'm guessing it's something to do with the cellular antennas being switched off in airplane mode.

Comment: Well "obviously" when you measure the high values, some circuits which operate at a high frequency and which are not shielded (inside a metal shielded area in the phone) are activated.

Comment: Somehow I doubt that these applications are any accurate.

Comment: Can you please provide context as to what this "EMF tester" instrument is, preferably with a link to a datasheet? Electromagnetic compatibility is a complicated field (pardon the pun).

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding the values that you state. You say "I get a very low measure (<1mG)", then you say "I get a very high value, something as 35μG". From where I am sitting, 35μG is a very much smaller amount than 1 mG. Please clarify your measurements and update your question.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie okay, but why such an enormous discrepancy between the external tester and the internal one? your observation would mean that no magnetic activity is detected anymore (by the external), just a few millimeters further on in space.. I'm very confused about this

Comment: @DwayneReid  Thanks, it was a lapsus.. the app test is in Tesla; now you see that there's a deep difference

Comment: @Peter I have no datasheet, it is a common radiation tester for personal use (range 0.1-200 mG)

Comment: @Bento - the EMF tester almost certainly only measures AC fields. The magnetometer only DC fields of which the Earth's magnetic field is the most significant.

Comment: @Bento What sort of radiation? You have a device which is (presumably) giving you output in Gauss. Is it an AC gaussmeter? If so, over what frequency range does it measure?

Comment: @Peter good comment. It is very likely an AC, in fact it doesn't detect earth emf. Sorry for frequency, I have no information about it.. but don't you think the  35uT of the internal be really an exaggerate value? (please see also my comment to user Sunnyskyguy below)

Comment: @KevinWhite this could be the right answer.. but don't you think 35uT is a bit exaggerate+

Comment: @Bento - Sounds reasonable for Earth's magnetic field - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_magnetic_field

Comment: @KevinWhite yes, yesterday I noticed this by a simple wiki-search; it was the Sunnyskyguy answer that deceived me because of G instead of T. Thank you very much, this discussion has been very useful and instructive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Earth's magnetic field is about  30uG at the equator and 60 uG  at the poles.
A small solar flare can cause 200uG.

For RF measurements you must also consider the power and  Bandwidth of your magnetic fields to make reasoned comparisons.

1 T = 10,000 G

So 1 mG= 0.1 uT

Comment: Do you mean that the measure by the phone might be falsified by geographic mf? But the app says that to overcome this inconvenience it tries to take calibrate field from the system.. and anyway 35 uT seems to be an exaggerate value. Moreover, why does the external tester says almost null field? Is it perhaps calibrate in order not to consider Earth emf?

Comment: sorry, I was wrong: It says to overcome the inconvenience of interferences by fields of the internal electronic circuits

Comment: Okay, after a little search, that makes sense, but the correct data are 30-60 uT, not Gauss.  I guess the problem is so solved